# Access violation parsing XML-file to clientdataset

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2010

Below a procedure to read an xml file into a clientdataset.
My code leads to a access violation error in the 2nd iteration of the 'd-loop' that I don't understand. 
daynode.childnodes results in message: Access violation at 00000000 accessing 00000000

In the first iteration dayNode.childnodes is a pointer to a list with nodes (IXMLnodelist). In the 2nd iteration the dayNode jump to the 2nd day-tag. The 2nd  has also some children in the file, but why does this lead to the error?

update: I added the addTocds and encodeStrToTdate procedures. The cds has the following fields ('Projectnr': string, 'weeknr': integer ,'jaar': integer, 'ma'...'zo': float)
It look there is something wrong in the addTocds procedure (locate) because if I replace 'if locate..then' with 'if false then', every record is added to the cds.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<ROOT>
    <DAY>
        <DATE>12-10-2019</DATE>
        <STATUS > 1 </STATUS>
        <PROJECTS>
            <PROJECT  nr = "190000"> 5</PROJECT>
            <PROJECT  nr = "190001"> 3</PROJECT>
        </PROJECTS>
    </DAY>
    <DAY>
        <DATE>11-10-2019</DATE>
        <STATUS > 1 </STATUS>
        <PROJECTS>
            <PROJECT nr =  "190000"> 3.4 </PROJECT>
            <PROJECT nr = "190001"> 4   </PROJECT>
        </PROJECTS>
    </DAY>
    <DAY>
        <DATE>13-10-2019</DATE>
        <STATUS > 2 </STATUS>
        <PROJECTS>
            <PROJECT nr = "190000"> 6 </PROJECT>
            <PROJECT nr = "190001"> 7 </PROJECT>
        </PROJECTS>
    </DAY>              
</ROOT>
```

```
const
  daysOfWeek: array [ 1 .. 7 ] of string = ( 'ma', 'di', 'wo', 'do', 'vr', 'za', 'zo' );

procedure addTocds( cds: Tclientdataset; dag: integer; week: integer; jaar: integer; pn: string; uren: double );
// dag: day of the week
// week: week of the year
  try
     with cds do
     begin
      if not active then Open;
      first;
      if locate('PROJECTNR;WEEKNR;JAAR', varArrayOf( [pn, week, jaar] ), [loCaseInsensitive] ) then
      begin
           Edit;
           FieldByName( daysOfWeek[ dag ] ).asfloat := uren; //floattostr( uren );
           post;
      end
      else
      begin
          cds.first;
          append;
          FieldByName( daysOfWeek[ dag ] ).asfloat := uren; 
          fieldbyname('PROJECTNR').asstring := pn;
          FieldByName('WEEKNR').asinteger := week; 
          FieldByName('JAAR').asinteger := jaar; 
          Post;
       end;
     end;
    except
        on E:exception do
        begin
             outputdebugstring(Pchar(e.message));
        end;
    end;
  end;

// the strTodate routine result in 3-12-1899 in all cases so I made this (temporarily) function
function encodeStrToTdate(xmlstring: string ): TDate;
var
  position :integer;
  daystr, monthstr, yearstr: string;
begin
  position :=pos('-', xmlstring);
  daystr := copy(xmlstring, 1, position-1);
  delete(Xmlstring,1,position);
  position :=pos('-', xmlstring);
  monthstr := copy(xmlstring, 1, position-1);
  delete(Xmlstring,1,position);
  yearstr := xmlstring;
  result := encodedate(strtoint(yearstr), strtoint(monthstr), strtoint(daystr));
end;

 // lees XML en laadt de XML in een TXMLdocument en open het document
procedure TAVIVparseXML.parseXML( XMLdoc: TXMLdocument; cds: Tclientdataset );
  var // XMLdoc : TXMLdocument;
    statusnode, mainnode, dayNode, datenode, projectNode, projectsNode: IXMLnode;
    dayNodes: IXMLnodelist;
    uren: string;
    d,p : integer;
    datestr: string;
    pn: string;
    dateobj : Tdate;
  begin
    try
    mainnode := XMLdoc.DocumentElement; // ROOT
    dayNodes := mainnode.childnodes;
    for d := 0 to mainnode.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do // DAY
    begin
       dayNode := daynodes.nodes[d]; //mainnode.ChildNodes[de]; //.nodes[de];//.get(d); //[ d ]; // DAY
       if (daynode.NodeName = 'DAY') then
       begin
         dateNode := dayNode.childnodes.FindNode('DATE');
         projectsNode := dayNode.childnodes.findNode('PROJECTS');
         statusNode := dayNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('STATUS');
         if(((dateNode <> nil) and (projectsNode <> nil)) and ((statusNode <> nil))) then
         begin
           datestr := dateNode.text;
           dateobj := encodeStrToTDate(datestr);
           if projectsNode <> nil then
           begin
              for p := 0 to projectsNode.childnodes.Count - 1 do //PROJECTS-> PROJECT
              begin
                projectNode := projectsNode.childnodes.nodes[p]; //.get(p);
                pn := projectNode.attributes['nr'];
                uren := Trim(projectNode.text);
                addTocds( cds, dayOfTheweek(dateobj), weekoftheyear(dateobj), yearOf(dateobj), pn,strTofloat(uren));
              end;
           end;
         end;
       end;
    end;
    except// finally
       outputdebugstring(Pchar('error parseXML'));      // freeandnil(XMLdoc);
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Presumably you are using MSXML.Pas, the supplied import unit. Which version of MSXml.Dll was it generated from? The one for Seattle, f.i. is from C:\WINDOWS\system32\msxml6.dll. according to the comments automatically generated by the importer.  Btw, please add the source of `encodeStrToTDate` to your q.

Comment: With `encodeStrToDate` and `addTocds` commented out, your code compiles and runs fine in Delphi Seattle.  So you need to edit your q so that the code it contains constitutes an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Otherwise it will likely be closed and then no-one can post an answer to it.  In future, please post an MRE in the first place.

Comment: @MartynA So we're calling them MRE's now? I remember when it was SSCCE. MRE reminds me of military food.

Comment: @JerryDodge:  Yup, apparently. I preferred MCVE myself ...

Comment: I always just use the [`[mcve]` magic-link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which redirects to whatever the latest article is (which is currently the [`[mre]` article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: the version is MSXml6.dll in delphi 2010
And thanks for the link about MRE.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution but don't know yet why this is the solution. because of my lack of knowledge about interfaces. The xmldoc object should be of type Ixmldocument instead of TXMLdocument. After this change, everything works well.